# how to build a new variable by extract a string from another variable

Tags: r

I have df that looks like this, and I would like to build a new variable`Main` if `Math|ELA` in Subject. The sample data and my codes are:

```
df<- structure(list(Subject = c("Math", "Math,ELA", "Math,ELA, PE", 
"PE, Math", "ART,ELA", "PE,ART")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df<-df %>%
+ mutate(Main=case_when (grepl("Math|ELA", Subject)~ paste0(str_extract_all(df$Subject, "Math|ELA"))))
```

However my outcome looks like following, not the one I like. What did I do wrong? I feel that my codes complicated the simple step. Any better solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_extract_all` returns a `list`.  We need to loop over the `list` and `paste/str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
  mutate(Main = case_when(grepl("Math|ELA", Subject)~ 
        map_chr(str_extract_all(Subject, "Math|ELA"), toString)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Subject      Main     
#  <chr>        <chr>    
#1 Math         Math     
#2 Math,ELA     Math, ELA
#3 Math,ELA, PE Math, ELA
#4 PE, Math     Math     
#5 ART,ELA      ELA      
#6 PE,ART       <NA>
```

---

Or another option is `separate_rows` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(Subject) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>%
  summarise(Main = toString(intersect(Subject, c("Math", "ELA"))), 
       .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  select(Main) %>%
  bind_cols(df, .)
```

---

NOTE: `paste` by itself doesn't do anything and in a `list`, we need to loop over the `list`

---

Or another option is to use

```
trimws(gsub("(Math|ELA)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\w+", "", df$Subject, perl = TRUE), whitespace = ",\\s*")
#[1] "Math"     "Math,ELA" "Math,ELA" "Math"     "ELA"      ""
```

Comment: Thanks. If we don't use `str_extract_all`, any better way?

Comment: @Stataq you could use `separate_rows` and then extract the strings as well

Comment: @Stataq updatd with another option

Comment: Could you also show me how to use `separate_rows` to do this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `regmatches`

```
transform(
  df,
  Main = sapply(
    regmatches(Subject, gregexpr("Math|ELA", Subject)),
    function(x) replace(toString(x), !length(x), NA)
  )
)
```

which gives

```
       Subject      Main
1         Math      Math
2     Math,ELA Math, ELA
3 Math,ELA, PE Math, ELA
4     PE, Math      Math
5      ART,ELA       ELA
6       PE,ART      <NA>
```